MacOS computer can't connect to Windows SMB share if it requires a login
I have a Windows 11 computer that I use as a home server on which I have shared some folders to access on a macOS Sonoma computer.
The Mac can access the shares that are accessible publicly(the "Everyone" group is given permission to read), but cannot access the shares that require a login(the only item in the permissions list is a user that I created and has full access to the share).
I know that the share that requires a login is accessible because I can access it from another Windows PC, it's just the macOS computer that can't access it and it doesn't even let me type in credentials, it just says "You do not have permission to access this server."
What am I doing wrong?
